# How to hide public folder from https with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, zend-framework2

I need to hide the public folder in the URL with HTTPs.

My site has two entry options: www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com.br (The first address redirects to the second).

I have already done some tests with the line of code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ public. * $ Https: //% {HTTP_HOST} / public / $ 1 [L, R = 301]
```

It works fine when I type in the browser the URL: www.mysite.com.br (which is the official address), because it appears HTTPs, however when I enter www.mysite.com it does not enter as HTTPs, because it is a redirect.

If I put in htaccess this way:

```
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST}! ^ Www \. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https: //% {HTTP_HOST} / public / $ 1 [L, R = 301]
```

Both addresses enter correctly (with HTTPs), but the "public" folder appears at the front: www.mysite.com.br/public/

I need to hide the public folder, so typing the two addresses I can view the HTTPs.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public/$1 [L,R=301]
# RewriteRule ^public.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
 RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Uncomment lines below when uploading to the live server
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]

 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|tif|js|css|xls|xlsx|zip|rar|pdf|ods|ots)$ 
 public/index.php [NC,F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please review entry options `www.mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com`.

Comment: RewriteBase /public/ this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I made many other attempts and still did not succeed.